# PySpark's "DataFrameLike" type vs pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, type-hinting

Spark 3.1 introduced type hints for python (hooray!) but I am puzzled as to why the return type of the toPandas method is "DataFrameLike" instead of pandas.DataFrame - see here: https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/conversion.pyi

Because of this mypy throws all sorts of errors if I try to use any of the pandas df methods on an object that's the result of calling toPandas. For example

```
df = spark_df.toPandas()
df.to_csv(out_path, index=False)
```

results in the error message

```
error: "DataFrameLike" has no attribute "to_csv"
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Same problem here... can not do any pandas transformation with a DataFrameLike objet...

Answer (score 1):

I believe this issue is fixed by this recent commit (dated Dec 22, 2021): https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/a70006d9a7b578721d152d0f89d1a894de38c25d

Right now when you use `.toPandas()` and print out type, it will actually give you Pandas DataFrame.

To read more about it, since your link is broken, here's the source code for [DataFrameLike](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/8fef5bb616b2633041c1284de2dac1f611e50ce3/python/pyspark/sql/pandas/_typing/__init__.py)

So make sure you update your pyspark to the latest version.

Comment: Linking to the spark issue [SPARK-34544](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-34544 "pyspark toPandas() should return pd.DataFrame by Rafal Wojdyla"). Looks like the fix was released in [version 3.3.0](https://spark.apache.org/releases/spark-release-3-3-0.html).

Answer (score 1):

To fix the `mypy` warnings:

`cast` has no effect at runtime, but it tells `mypy` to treat it as a real `pandas.DataFrame` for the purposes of type-checking.

I like the other answers here, and maybe you can fix it without this `cast` trick/hack, but I'm giving this as another option

```
import pandas as pd
from typing import cast

df = cast(pd.DataFrame, spark_df.toPandas())
df.to_csv(out_path, index=False)
```