# MyPy on PySpark error: "DataFrameLike" has no attribute "values"

Tags: pyspark, mypy

I am developing a program in PySpark 3.2.1.

`Mypy == 0.950`

One of the operations requires to transform information of a small DataFrame into a list.

##### The code is:

```
result = df.select("col1","col2","col3").toPandas().values.tolist()
```

I need to convert it to a list because I then broadcast the information and a pyspark broadcast can't be a DataFrame

##### For this code I get the following `mypy`  error:

```
error: "DataFrameLike" has no attribute "values"
```

##### I there something I might do to avoid the mypy error?

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/69179587/13106037

Comment: Why do you need to convert into pandas to get list of values?

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me.

```
>>> df=spark.read.option('header','true').csv("C:/Users/pc/Desktop/myfile.txt")
>>> df
DataFrame[col1: string, col2: string, col3: string]
>>> result = df.select("col1","col2","col3").toPandas().values.tolist()
>>> result
[['1', '100', '1001'], ['2', '200', '2002'], ['3', '300', '1421'], ['4', '400', '24214'], ['5', '500', '14141']]
```

what is Mypy here ?

Comment: MyPy is an optional static type checker. http://mypy-lang.org/index.html. The code works and executes but I use mypy to do improve code quality.